# Passing variable into block - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within my rails app, I am using this gem to interact with the Gmail API: https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail

Here is what I have in a method to send an email:

```
gmail = Gmail.connect(params[:email], params[:password])
@email = params[:email]

email = gmail.compose do
  to @email
  subject "Having fun in Puerto Rico!"
  body "Spent the day on the road..."
end
email.deliver!
```

I am getting this error:

```
An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.
```

The email variable is not able to pass into the block. What is causing this? How can I pass in a dynamic email address?

Comment: Does `@email` have any value? Is it blank or nil?

Comment: @email has a value before it is passed into the block, within the block it ends up having a value of nil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure it happens because `@email` is an instance variable, binded to `self` (somewhat equal to `self.email`). And gmail module can easily change `self` inside block using methods like `instance_eval` or `class_eval`, so-called "scope gates". It's regular feature for ruby metaprogramming.

Just use a simple variable, it will be caught by continuation.

```
email_to = params[:email]
email = gmail.compose do
    to email_to
    ...
end
```

And I would strongly recommend not to use instance variables as temp - they represent state of object. Use local variables, that's what they are designed for.

Comment: This method is in my controller. I just tried this and it gives me the exact same error.

Comment: When I try passing in params[:email] I get this error: undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Mail::Message:70204364613700, Multipart: false, Headers: >

Comment: Well, strange, bad luck then. But still, check `self.class` and `self.inspect` inside block.

Comment: `params` is not a variable, it's a method for some base controller (`ActionController`?), so it's also binded to `self` and not accessible inside block.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much!!! :)))